# Problemas con el control de versiones de node en VCODE, desde window

Tags: nvm

Estoy tratando de cambiar la version de node, estoy utilizando nvm a traves de Ubuntu, ya instalé la ultima version de node y la estoy usando en Ubuntu me aparece todo bien, el problema es que cuando voy al editor de codigo me dice que no reconoce node ni ninguna version, en el editor estoy utilizando powershell tal vez sea por eso, aun asi intente utilizar la terminal de ubuntu en visual y no encontre una opcion

Ubuntu
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el editor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una opcion seria instalar node de forma manual con la ultima version, pero el detalle es que cada vez que quiera cambiar de version tengo que desinstalar e instalar otra version y por eso elegi nvm en Ubuntu

Comment: Lo que instalas en WSL no está disponible en Windows y viceversa. Debes instalar Node en Windows, para que PowerShell lo pueda ejecutar. Otra forma sería arrancar VSCode desde WSL para que use la terminal integrada de Ubuntu.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, intente hacerlo con wsl pero al momento de seleccionar una carpeta y escogia mi carpeta local, me abria el proyecto pero no aparece la terminal de ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa es ejecutar el vscode desde la máquina de ubunto del WSL, estando en el ubuntu puedes ejecutar

```
code .
```